# Writing a string to a framebuffer device?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, framebuffer

This is on a Raspberry Pi, Linux 3.13, bash 4.2

Connected is a SPI 320x240 Display which is displaying a background image (I used `fbi` to display the image, the `cat /dev/fb1 > framebuffer.contents`, then whenever I need the image I do `cat framebuffer.contents > /dev/fb1` to save the looong startup time of `fbi`).

Now I'd like to "amend" my image by a (changing) one-line text (a few word, the time, ...). Therefore I am looking for a way to write a string, from bash, to a specific location within the framebuffer. Eg. a tool is needed that **a)** converts a string given to some sort of framebuffer-redabe graphic (`ppm`?), then **b)** inserts that resulting image into a given part of the framebuffer.

Any ideas? Or is my good old bash-and-unix-tools approach over it's head here and I need to look into .... ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure in which situations you need to do what you do. But maybe you could "misuse" [splashutils/fbsplash](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fbsplash.berlios/files/) for your needs? It's rather meant to display a framebuffer bootsplash but has some tools to tinker with a fb (testing tools for splashscreen development as an example).
You can read about how to use it on the [Gentoo wiki](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Fbsplash).

Aside from that maybe you can find some inspiration on a thread at [Unix & Linux - How to use /dev/fb0 as a console from userspace, or output text to it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20458/how-to-use-dev-fb0-as-a-console-from-userspace-or-output-text-to-it).

Comment: Thanks for the latter link, I had already read that. It deals with text-only, ie. having (another) console on the framebuffer device.